# Redirect not always working with JQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, redirect

I am having some issues getting the jquery ui dialog redirecting always.  When I click a delete link it asks if you are sure.  If you click the delete button it should be redirected.  THe problem is it doesnt always redirect the first time.  It usually only works after you click the dialog window delete the second time.  Does anyone know why this might happen?  I have tried using the redirect in multiple places including after the query happens and before and after the delete query closes.

### Page where dialog redirects(at bottom);

```
<a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>

<script>
    var id = "";
    //run function after jquery dialong confirm
    //step 1 - the action
    $(".delete").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        //console.log(id); // check you get it first
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });
    //step 2 - the dialog modal
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        resizable: true,
        height: 100,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function() {
                //console.log(id + " made it to dialog"); // make sure our id makes it this far
                deleteUser(id); // run delete photo function
                window.location.href = "http://www.speechvive.com/adminSLP.php";
                $(this).dialog("close");

            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    //step 3 - php function
    function deleteUser(user_id) {
        //console.log(user_id + " made it to function"); // make sure our id makes it this far
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/adminSLP.php#delete",
            data: {user_id: user_id}
        }).done(function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            //no message bc we did a fadeOut
            //var msg would show any errors from our php file
        });
    }
    ;
</script>
```

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow** - please provide code that identifies your problem easily in the shortest form, avoid posting large blocks of code.

Comment: please only post relevant code!

Comment: Sorry about that.  I posted the code that might be helpful.  Let me know if you need more of my code

Comment: do you see any errors when you click Delete button for the first time..?